# Does setting the property serverTimezone in jdbcUrl connection url affects read/write of timestamp value from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, timestamp, timezone, mysql-5.7

My mysql server is running in PDT(-07:00) timezone
My code is running on a server in UTC timezone
I am using *mysql-connector-java* version "8"

If I set property `serverTimezone=UTC` in `jdbcUrl` connection url, does it

1. affect the timestamp value being read from mysql database?
2. If (1) yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I set property serverTimezone=UTC in jdbcUrl connection url, does
> it affect the timestamp value being read from mysql database?

Yes, it does. Instead of my explanation, I am quoting below the excerpt from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-other-changes.html:

> The server's time zone is overridden by setting the Connector/J
> connection property serverTimezone (for example,
> serverTimezone=Europe/Paris).

**Recommendation:** I recommend you use `serverTimezone=UTC` and then convert the retrieved timestamp to the required time-zone in your application code. Again, to support this recommendation, I am quoting below the excerpt from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-known-issues-limitations.html:

> When Connector/J retrieves timestamps for a daylight saving time (DST)
> switch day using the getTimeStamp() method on the result set, some of
> the returned values might be wrong. The errors can be avoided by using
> the following connection options when connecting to a database:

```
    serverTimezone=UTC
```